# Can we use GitLab as host for source code with AWS CDK pipeline?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have a repository in GitLab (Lambda Functions) and want to work with the AWS CDK pipeline (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/cdk-pipelines-continuous-delivery-for-aws-cdk-applications) to develop CI/CD pipeline. In AWS CDK docs there is nowhere mention about Gitlab. Will really appreciate it if someone can confirm this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only Bitbucket, GitHub, GitHub Enterprise Server actions are supported natively with codepipelines at the moment. You will need a custom lambda for gitlab.
https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/git-to-s3-using-webhooks/ can help you with that.

You can use s3 source actions after implementing up git to s3 logic

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer comes too late for you:

What you can do:

These providers are supported at the moment:

"GitHub; you can also use CodeStar or AWS CodeCommit"

(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cdk_pipeline.html)

You can setup an empty repository in AWS CodeCommit and then use the GitLab repository mirroring to replicate the changes to AWS CodeCommit.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/